# Как в jQuery задать полную охватываемую высоту страницы?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как в jQuery задать полную охватываемую высоту страницы? Делал innerHeight, screen.Height, document.height, window.Height и ничего не помогает. Ни охватывают экран, а не весь документ. Как я могу сделать чтобы забрать всю длину документа? Чтобы при изменении размера окна она не искажалась и не менялась

Comment: а `$(document).height()` не помогло? странно.

Comment: Иногда надо учитывать отступы, рамки ... Тогда используйте [.outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если у тебя все содержимое находится, например, в блоке с классом `.wrapper`, то нужно просто взять высоту этого блока:

```
$(".wrapper").height();
```